# How to setup Flatbuffers environment with eclipse IDE ? What plugins or software I will need to install ? Thanks?

Tags: flatbuffers

I want to use flabuffers for an embedded project. How to setup Flatbuffers environment with eclipse IDE ? What plugins or software I will need to install ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There are no plugins. You use a command line tool (flatc) to generate Java code which you can include in your project.